# How to get transaction fee

Tags: blockchain.info, transaction-fees, api

I have transaction id, how can I get a fee of this transaction from blockchain.info? For example I see that 
this transaction https://blockchain.info/tx/https://blockchain.info/tx/963b9f407aabf8ebca660763bc5d3e8800eb6a5dffaf692cd061f0525ee770e1 has 0.00105453 BTC fee, but there is no such number in json data https://blockchain.info/tx/963b9f407aabf8ebca660763bc5d3e8800eb6a5dffaf692cd061f0525ee770e1?format=json

I'm new in bitcoin and I'm trying to write some scripts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I think I have found how to calculate transaction fee.
So we have to subtract sum of `out` values from `inputs.prev_out.value`.

Comment: it should be calculate from json out and input value subtract.